# Fortify scans over multiple machines

Tags: fortify

We work in a team and run Fortify software on our machines locally. We all have our project code setup in different root directories e.g I have project code at C:\work\development\, few of my colleagues have something like C:\Development\mainCodeLine\ etc etc. i.e. the root-folder where the project-code resides differs. Initially only I was working on Fortify but now there are many members of the team running Fortify. We currently share the FPR file that is saved in repository. We download it from the repository and run SCA commands over the same file so as to retain the details like hidden/suppressed issues. Over the period of time we observed that :

1. The Unique Instance ID that gets generated is unique over a single machine only. i.e. the Unique Instance ID remains same over scans on my machine only and it changes when the scan is carried out in my team-mate's machine. Is there any way we can configure Fortify to keep it same over multiple scans over multiple machines? Because of this we can't use the Unique Instance ID in the filter-file.
2. If I and my team-mate run scans parallelly on 2 separate machines on same code (only the project's root directory differs as stated earlier) then is there any way we can integrate these 2 reports?

Answer (score 3):

There are indeed methods to combine scan results generated on different machines.  I believe that the best way to accomplish this is to utilize the Fortify Software Security Center (SSC).  Users conduct "fresh" scans each time, and when uploaded into a project in SSC, they will be merged - retaining any previous auditing information.

An alternative approach is to use the command line FPRUtility.  (I don't have an install in front of me at the moment so the name might be slightly off - but it's in the bin directory along with sourceanalyzer and auditworkbench).  The `-h` option should provide the info to get started merging FPRs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If different IIDs are being changed by a different overall root, that seems a bug. SCA uses the canonical root usually so it shouldn't make any difference where its placed. 
Xelco52 had it partially correct, but if you want to merge when they have different IIDs, it's best to use FPRUtility with the `-forceMigration` option, such as:

```
FPRUtility -merge -project Results1.fpr -source Results2.fpr -f mergedResults.fpr -forceMigration
```

You should also be able to get this affect in AWB by setting `com.fortify.model.ForceIIDMigration=true` in Core/config/fortify.properties (and restarting AWB)

Comment: I agree that this should work, but somehow my mergedResults.fpr always turns out to be equivalent to the Results1.fpr. The Results2.fpr is not being merged...

Answer (score 2):

Look into using HP Fortify Software Security Center (SSC) if possible. This will allow users to upload scans to a central repository and merge results. This helps create a running history of scans and know who uploaded what.

Also this will allow your team to use a feature called "Collaborative Audit" that will let each developer pull the latest FPR down from Software Security Center (SSC) and into their IDE. Developers can then make changes and push back up to SSC where results are once again merged.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think merge is the right approach. I would do it this way:
(1) Among all developers (user#), on their own machine, establish the naming convention of the ProjectRoot (point to user#'s code base, i.e. /home/user#/mycode) and WorkingDirectory (i.e. /local/sharebuild)

(2) Each user use the following commands on their own machine:
    (2a) CLEAN CACHE: ~/sourceanalyzer -b user# -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot=/home/user#/mycode -Dcom.fortify.WorkingDirectory=/local/sharebuild/ -logfile /local/sharebuild/user#.sca.log  -clean
    (2b) TRANSLATE: ~/sourceanalyzer -b user# -64 -Xmx11000M -Xss24M -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot=/home/user#/mycode/ -Dcom.fortify.WorkingDirectory=/local/sharebuild/ -logfile  /local/sharebuild/user#.sca.log  -source 1.5 -cp 'your_class_path'  -extdirs 'your *.war file'  '/home/user#/mycode/**/*'

(3) INTEGRATE ALL INTERMEDIATE CODE TO THE BUILD MACHINE : each user copy his entire /local/sharebuild/sca#.## to the centralized build machine, under directory /local/sharebuild/sca#.##/build/ (you will find sub directory ./user# (each user's build id) which contains all intermediate code tree (.nst).

(4) SCAN: on the build server, do scan with command:
~/sourceanalyzer -b user1 -b user2 -b user3 -b user# -64 -Xmx11000M -Xss24M -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot=/home/user#/mycode/ -Dcom.fortify.WorkingDirectory=/local/sharebuild/ -logfile  /local/sharebuild/scan.sca.log -scan -f build_all.fpr

The step 4 will pick up all .nst (normalized syntax tree) files and performing the scan.

If each user mount his portion of code to the centralized machine on step 2a, then step 3 can be omitted.